# Figure caption alignment

Tags: captions, align

[image]

Hello, I need this alining of caption, and also this font of "Slika D.8"

Comment: Have a look at the `caption` package. It supports sffamily-style captions and also the hanging of the caption text. Try this: `\captionsetup{format=hang, labelfont=\sffamily}`.

Comment: It's not working :/

Comment: Please post what you've got so far (MWE). Btw: I was wrong with the `labelfont` (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one option: Using `caption` and its options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelfont=sf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \caption{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```